# array_count_values() isn't working with eloquent pluck

Tags: php, laravel, duplicates

After executing

```
$viewlogs = ViewLog::where(condition)
             ->pluck('user_id');
```

I get [11,33,22,11] but when I apply **array_count_values()** in this method error **array_count_values(): Can only count string and integer values** occurs.

When I convert it to an array like this

```
foreach($viewlogs as $v) {
 array_push($arr,$v);
  }
```

which also returns **[11,33,22,11]**. Here **array_count_values()** method works.
Please tell me what I am doing in the first place.

Comment: because pluck retourns a collection, use the toArray() method to get array from the collection, .. ->pluck(...)->toArray()

Comment: Please do not roll back edits that objectively improve your post, such as by correcting grammar. Once you've posted your question here, it's explicitly allowed for others to edit the post. See [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning a `Collection` type, you can use the `count()` helper hemthod by using:

```
   $viewlogs = ViewLog::where(condition)
                    ->pluck('user_id');
   $count = $viewLogs->count();
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but array_count_values() [returns number of duplicates] and count() are completely different methods

Comment: try `array_count_values($viewlogs->toArray()) ;`

Comment: yeah toArray() worked @asma_mech commented the solution